# How to edit an Swift array in a compact form

Tags: ios, swift

Given the following example code:

```
class Loader {
    var posts = [Post]()

    init() {
        for i in 131...141 {
            posts.append(PostImpl(id: i))
        }
    }
}

protocol Post {
    var id:Int {get}
    var readByUser: Bool {get set}
}

class PostImpl: Post {

    var id: Int
    var readByUser: Bool = false;

    init(id:Int) {
        self.id = id
    }

}
```

I want to mark the item with id == 135 as `readByUser=true`. Is there some way of doing this in a more compact/readable/easy way than:

```
let loader = Loader()

for (index,post) in loader.posts.enumerated() {
    if post.id == 135 {
        loader.posts[index].readByUser = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be this if you want short:

```
loader.posts[loader.posts.index(where: { $0.id == 135 })!].readByUser = true
```

Or check optional if you want:

```
if let index = loader.posts.index(where: { $0.id == 135 }) {
    loader.posts[index].readByUser = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var loader = Loader()
loader.posts.filter { $0.id == 135 }.forEach { $0.readByUser = true }
```

This also looks good but because you have an array of items that implement a `protocol`. If you don't tell `Swift` that this is a `class protocol`, it will assume that it can be implemented by `struct`.

So one more change if you're going to use it.

```
protocol Post : class {
    var id:Int {    get }
    var readByUser: Bool {  get set }
}
```